# unexpected end of input error, again

Tags: php, jquery

I have no idea what I am doing wrong. I have a dialog that a user can enter an address and click ok and it inserts that information entered into the database. I keep getting "unexpected end of input" error or "unexpected token" errors. I have a feeling it has something to do with the serialize property in the jquery ajax function but I'm not sure.

I don't know how I can echo back the variables to see if they're even getting the data from the fields or the sql statement. I've tried a lot and it either crashes the page or it gives me the same "unexpected" errors.

Please help! :(

jQuery Code:

```
    $('#ChangeOfAddress').click(function() {
        //change of address dialog
        $( "#ChangeAddressDialog" ).dialog({
            width:500,
            modal:true,
            closeOnEscape:true,
            buttons: [ 
                { text: "Ok", type: "submit", click: function() { 
                        $.ajax({
                            url: "classes/add-address.php",
                            type: "POST",
                            data: $("#main_form").serialize(),
                            dataType: 'json',
                            error: function(SMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){
                                alert("An error has occurred making the request: " + errorThrown)

                            },
                            success: function(result){
                                //do stuff here on success such as modal info
                                //$("#main_form").submit();
                                $(this).dialog("close");
                            }
                        })
                    } 
                },
                { text: "Close", click: function() { $(this).dialog( "close" ); } } ]
        });//end dialog
    });
```

PHP Page: (ez sql insert returns a bool value)

```
<?php
require_once('../config.php');

$sqlCheck = ''; 
$parcel_id = isset($_POST['ParcelId']) ? $_POST['ParcelId'] : null;
$address1 = isset($_POST['Address1']) ? $_POST['Address1'] : null;
$address2 = isset($_POST['Address2']) ? $_POST['Address2'] : null;
$city = isset($_POST['City']) ? $_POST['City'] : null;
$state = isset($_POST['State']) ? $_POST['State'] : null;
$zip = isset($_POST['Zip']) ? $_POST['Zip'] : null;
$country = isset($_POST['Country']) ? $_POST['Country'] : null;

$db = new ezSQL_mysql(DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME, DB_HOST);
$result = $db->query("INSERT INTO change_of_address (parcel_id, address_1, address_2, City, State, Zip, Country) VALUES ('" . $parcel_id . "','" . $address1 . "','" . $address2 . "','" . $city . "','" . $state . "','" . $zip . "','" . $country . "')");
if ($result == 1) {
    echo true;
} else {
    echo false;
}

//$sqlCheck = "INSERT INTO change_of_address (parcel_id, address_1, address_2, City, State, Zip, Country) VALUES ('" . $parcel_id . "','" . $address1 . "','" . $address2 . "','" . $city . "','" . $state . "','" . $zip . "','" . $country . "')";



?>
```

I tried adding the following but it didn't return any errors:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
```

Comment: Where are you getting the errors? On the server? Or on the browser console? Does it say which line numbers it's erroring out at?

Comment: It doesn't say anything. Just an alert that says "unexpected end of input" error or "unexpected token"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that your `$.ajax` call is expecting a JSON response, but your PHP file is echoing literal `true` or `false`. Those are not JSON responses. You need to return valid JSON, something like

```
if ($result == 1) {
    echo '{"success":true}';
} else {
    echo '{"success":false}';
}
```

Comment: It worked! Now I need to find out why its not inserting the information into the database! :(

Comment: Glad it helped! Please remember to accept the answer. :) As for the database, you should post a new question. Please be aware that you are very vulnerable to SQL injection based on the above code, and you *will* get hacked.

Comment: While in this simple scenario the posted solution is the best, it might be noteworthy that one may/should use `json_encode` if more data is to be returned from the script ;)

Comment: Thank you both!! I cant up vote it won't let me says I don't have enough reputation but I did the check thing under. It is an internal application only so hopefully no SQL injection worries. I just need to get it working and get it out there then I can worry about making it more secure.